# MeijerG gives the wrong result? (V10.2)

Tags: numerics, special-functions

```
alpha = 6.39;
beta = 3.69;
a1 = (1 - alpha)/2;
a2 = (2 - alpha)/2;
a3 = (1 - beta)/2;
a4 = (2 - beta)/2;
a5 = 1;
b1 = 0;
b2 = 1/2;
SNR = 0;
SNR0 = 10^(SNR/10);
z = 2*(SNR0/(alpha*beta))^2;
p1 = 2^(alpha + beta - 3)/(Pi*Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[alpha]*Gamma[beta]);
p2 = MeijerG[{{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {a5}}, {{b1, b2}, {}}, z, 1]
```

> 108.522

This was done in V10.2.

The result of `p2` is expected to be `12.83559958`, doubled checked in `Maple` and `Matlab` and confirmed from other research papers.

Syntax is expected to be correct too.

What is going on here?

Screenshot from Maple:
[image]

Comment: Mathematica v9 gives the same result

Comment: @belisarius I dont know anything about this as I am not a pure mathematician. I have never learnt this either. But is this answer correct? or equivalent to the Maple answer? I highly doubt it.

Comment: `N[MeijerG[Rationalize[{{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {a5}}], {{b1, b2}, {}}, 
  Rationalize[z, 0], 1], 20]` gives `12.835599581687294282`. This is using software rather than hardware arithmetic, that is to say, error estimates and refinement will be better. Offhand I do not know whether this also indicates deficiency in the machine number evaluation.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I will forward your answer to the OP in the Chinese community. Is there any particular reason for the `20` in `N[ ..,20]`, or is it just some precision it happen to be working (getting the correct answer) ?

Comment: I usually use 20 digits when I want a result using modest precision in software arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel Lichtblau showed in his comment, use exact numbers (or `Rationalize`) for input values

```
alpha = 639/100;
beta = 369/100;
a1 = (1 - alpha)/2;
a2 = (2 - alpha)/2;
a3 = (1 - beta)/2;
a4 = (2 - beta)/2;
a5 = 1;
b1 = 0;
b2 = 1/2;
SNR = 0;
SNR0 = 10^(SNR/10);
z = 2*(SNR0/(alpha*beta))^2;
p1 = 2^(alpha + beta - 3)/(Pi*Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[alpha]*Gamma[beta]);
```

Then use `arbitrary-precision` of at least 10 digits rather than `machine precision`

```
{#, N[MeijerG[{{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {a5}}, {{b1, b2}, {}}, z], #]} & /@ 
  Range[3, 20] // Grid
```

[image]